# Cómo ACTUALIZAR el contenido de un campo según la fecha actual

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy iniciando en la programación PHP, tengo un proyecto conectado con PDO a MYSQL que tiene los siguientes campos:

ID, DETALLE, FECHA_INICIO, FECHA_FIN, ESTADO

El campo ESTADO puede tener uno de los siguientes datos:

'POR REGISTRAR' Cuando la fecha actual del sistema es menor al campo FECHA_INICIO`

'EN REGISTRO' Cuando la fecha actual del sistema está entre la FECHA_INICIO y FECHA_FIN

'REGISTRADO' Cuando la fecha actual del sistema es mayor al campo FECHA_FIN

¿Cómo puedo hacer para que el campo ESTADO se actualice automáticamente en la base de datos según la fecha actual del sistema?

Intenté con:

```
$fecha_actual = date('Y-m-d');
$sql = "UPDATE Registros SET ESTADO='Sin Registrar' WHERE FECHA_INICIO > $fecha_actual";
```

Al parecer no está correcto.

Muchas gracias.

Comment: ¿Qué quieres decir con *al parecer no está correcto*? Si quieres que la actualización se haga de forma automática lo propio sería programar un evento, para la que la consulta se ejecute una vez al día por ejemplo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

y si le dejas:

```
$sql = "UPDATE Registros SET ESTADO='Sin Registrar' WHERE FECHA_INICIO > CURDATE()";
```

[Referencia oficial MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_curdate)